# как генерировать несколько <li> с дочерним элементом <a> с разным содержимым внутри в js

Tags: javascript

пытаюсь создать шапку сайта с навигацией используя только js хотел сгенерировать li с дочерним элементом "a" по 6 раз но не вышло,может кто показать пример?

Comment: Покажите, что пытались сделать - тогда поможем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно воспользоваться циклом.

```js
  const menu = document.getElementById('menu');
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let alink = document.createElement('A');
    alink.href = '#'; // 
    alink.textContent = i+1; // здесь можете указывать содержимое
    li.appendChild(alink);
    menu.appendChild(li);
  }
```

```html
<ul id='menu'></ul>
```